# How can I send emails using godaddys office 365 email and digital ocean droplet?

Tags: php, phpmailer, digital-ocean, godaddy-api

I need our application server to send emails to our clients through a mail server hosted on goddady

We use as a reference the case described in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-solve-emails-problems-after-site-is-migrated-to-digital-ocean

we add the MX records but the mailing does not work; we enclose the reporter errors by the library that we use:

**TECHNICAL DATA**

- OS: ubuntu 16.07
- Language: PHP 7.2
- mail library: phpmailer 6.0.5

**PHP MAILER CONFIGURATION**

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host =  'smtp.office365.net';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = MAIL_APP1;
$mail->Password = MAIL_APP1_PWD;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Port = 993; //SMTP_PORT;
```

**REPORTED ERRORS**

```
2018-09-14 16:21:51 SERVER - & gt; CLIENT: * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
[QwBPADIAUABSADAANgBDAEEAMAAwADUANQAuAG4AYQBtAHAAcgBkADAANgAuAHAAcgBvAGQALgBvAHUAdABsAG8AbwBrAC4AYwBvAG0A] * BYE Connection is closed. 13 
2018-09-14 16:21:51 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected 
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

**ACTUALIZATION**

**new configuration:**

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->DKIM_domain = '127.0.0.1';
$mail->Host =  'smtpout.secureserver.net';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = MAIL_APP1;
$mail->Password = MAIL_APP1_PWD;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Port = 465; //SMTP_PORT;
```

**new error:**

```
2018-09-20 01:34:47 Connection: opening to ssl://smtpout.secureserver.net:465, timeout=300, options=array()<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 Connection: opened<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 SMTP INBOUND: &quot;220 p3plsmtpa12-05.prod.phx3.secureserver.net :SMTPAUTH: ESMTP&quot;<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 220 p3plsmtpa12-05.prod.phx3.secureserver.net :SMTPAUTH: ESMTP<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: EHLO app.persaerp.com<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 SMTP INBOUND: &quot;250-p3plsmtpa12-05.prod.phx3.secureserver.net hello [167.99.172.180], secureserver.net&quot;<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 SMTP INBOUND: &quot;250-HELP&quot;<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 SMTP INBOUND: &quot;250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN&quot;<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 SMTP INBOUND: &quot;250-SIZE 30000000&quot;<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 SMTP INBOUND: &quot;250-PIPELINING&quot;<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 SMTP INBOUND: &quot;250-8BITMIME&quot;<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 SMTP INBOUND: &quot;250 OK&quot;<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 250-p3plsmtpa12-05.prod.phx3.secureserver.net hello [167.99.172.180], secureserver.net250-HELP250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN250-SIZE 30000000250-PIPELINING250-8BITMIME250 OK<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 Auth method requested: UNSPECIFIED<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 Auth methods available on the server: LOGIN,PLAIN<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 Requested auth method not available: <br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 Auth method selected: LOGIN<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: AUTH LOGIN<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 SMTP INBOUND: &quot;334 VXNlcm5hbWU6&quot;<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: aW5mb0BwZXJzYWVycC5jb20=<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 SMTP INBOUND: &quot;334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6&quot;<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: UGVyJGFFUlAyMDE4<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 SMTP INBOUND: &quot;535 Authentication Failed for info@persaerp.com. User does not have any relays assigned.&quot;<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 535 Authentication Failed for info@persaerp.com. User does not have any relays assigned.<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 Authentication Failed for info@persaerp.com. User does not have any relays assigned.<br>
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: QUIT<br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: <br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: <br>
2018-09-20 01:34:47 Connection: closed<br>
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.<br>
```

Comment: Your errors indicate that you are not authenticating against your SMTP service. Is your library / application sending authentication credentials to your mail server?

Comment: course i do that, i change mi configuration but error happend again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a giveaway in that error message: `The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service` - you should not be seeing a message about IMAP on an SMTP connection, and indeed, you're connecting to port 993, which is IMAP. You should be using port 465 or 587, but...

As the PHPMailer docs mention, GoDaddy blocks outbound SMTP by default, and forces you to relay via their own mail server. This breaks many email requirements, so you may want to find a better hosting provider.

Comment: Thank you for responding, so there's no sure way to do this process?

Comment: It depends on your exact requirements, but for example you would not be able to send from a yahoo address from within GoDaddy because it would fail their SPF checks.

Comment: i need to know if my configuration its ok, i changed the port to **465** with ssl encryption and this servers outlook.office365.com, smtp.office365.com can u help me with the correct configuration if something its wrong.

Comment: That sounds correct, though you should only need `$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';`. However, you're still going to run into the same problem that even if you have the correct config, GoDaddy is going to block it, so your script will fail or time out, and there's nothing you can do about that from your script. Read GoDaddy's documentation about how to send email.